# How to make environment that right-aligns the text?

Tags: environments

In my document, there is a collection of short stories each of which has a date after the end. I want to make an environment for those dates, that would (for now) right-align them, but will probably do something else (probably italicise them, or change their font). That's the reason I am not just using `flushright`.

I have tried defining that environment as:

> \newenvironment{storydate}
>   {\raggedleft}{}

However that did nothing, at least it did not right-align text within that environment.

Why did not that have an effect?

After all, putting `\raggedleft` before a paragraph does right-align it (and paragraphs after it".

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's not completely clear what you're about. Can you pleas be more specific?

Comment: @marmot because that's what it does according to documentation and experiment

Comment: @egreg "why doesn't that have any effect?", i guess

Comment: Why don’t you just use a comment rather than an environment, like `\newcommand{\storydate}[1]{\hfill\textit{#1}}`?

Comment: @Jasper no preferences one way or another

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite likely you don't need an environment, but simply a command.

```
\newcommand{\storydate}[1]{%
  \par                   % ensure vertical mode
  \nopagebreak           % we want no page break
  \vspace{\medskipamount}% some vertical space
  \hspace*{\fill}%       % fill the line
  \textit{#1}%           % the date
  \par                   % end the new paragraph
}
```

Full example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for interesting short stories

\newcommand{\storydate}[1]{%
  \par                   % ensure vertical mode
  \nopagebreak           % we want no page break
  \vspace{\medskipamount}% some vertical space
  \hspace*{\fill}%       % fill the line
  \textit{#1}%           % the date
  \par                   % end the new paragraph
}

\begin{document}

\section*{A nice story}

\lipsum[1-3]

\storydate{February 4, 2018}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Your approach with `\raggedleft` would work as well, but you should do

```
\newenvironment{storydate}{\par\raggedleft}{\par}
```

so that the group initiated by the environment doesn't end before TeX breaks the (single line) paragraph. However this would have the defect of allowing a page break between the end of the story and the date. See the `\nopagebreak` item in the code above. The `\par` in front of `\raggedleft` ensures the last paragraph of the story is broken into lines before the date is typeset.

Comment: Thanks, the bit about preventing page breaks is very important for me; I was about to ask a follow up question about it

Answer (score 2):

A simple  command will do:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\storydate}[1]{\par\noindent\makebox[\linewidth][r]{\itshape#1}\bigskip\par}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\storydate{\today}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that works. Where did i go wrong, though?

Comment: You should have added `\hfill` before `\raggedleft`,  I guess.